# Removing 0 values from a matrix in R

Tags: r

So i have a matrix that was generated using the distm() function to generate the distance between stations in a datatable and apply the minimum distance of each station to a new datatable but because it also compares each station with it self it has 0 as the minimum value for each row in the matrix. So i'm looking for a way to get rid of the 0's.

This is what i've used to generate the matrix:

```
library(geosphere)

mDis = distm( nStnData[,c("Longitude", "Latitude")], nStnData [,c("Longitude", "Latitude")], fun = distVincentyEllipsoid)
```

This is how i'm trying to apply the minimum distance for each station to the new datatable:

```
t$minDistance = apply(mDis, 1, min)
```

This is what it saves:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYuuZ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post R examples:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: If you want the minimum value that is not zero, why not `mDis2 <- mDis; mDis2[mDis2 == 0] <- Inf`. Then `apply(mDis2, 1, min)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the zero values to `Inf`and take the minimum of the resulting vector. This can be done without creating an extra matrix. Define an anonymous function in the call to `apply` to do it.

I will use the first example in `?distm` since the question does not have a reproducible example that we can copy&paste to an R session.

```
library(geosphere)

xy <- rbind(c(0,0),c(90,90),c(10,10),c(-120,-45))
mDis <- distm(xy)

apply(mDis, 1, function(x){
  x[x == 0] <- Inf
  min(x)
})
#[1]  1565109  8896111  1565109 12317881
```

Comment: Dude...you're the BEST. It worked. Tell me how did you learn R. Currently studying data science and need good sources to learn from.

Comment: @OmZPrime Start with the documentation that comes with R, file `R-intro.pdf`, and check out what CRAN has in its site.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to calculate the second-smallest value.

```
apply(mDis,1, function(x)sort(x)[2])
```

Comment: This worked as well... But between yours and  Rui barradas solution above which is faster.